# Calculate Means and Standard Deviation by columns in Hadoop

Tags: statistics, hadoop, machine-learning, mapreduce

I want to calculate means and standard deviation by columns in Hadoop.

I simple adopt single pass Naïve algorithm to MapReduce.
I tested it on multivariate data sets 455000x90 and 650000x120 and got speedup lower, more lower, then count of processors. For standalone and pseudo-distributed mode with 2 active cores I got speedup 0,4 = 20seconds / 53seconds for 455000x90.

Why my programm is not effective ? Is it possible to improve it ?

Mapper:

```java
public class CalculateMeanAndSTDEVMapper extends
       Mapper <LongWritable,
               DoubleArrayWritable,
               IntWritable,
               DoubleArrayWritable> {

    private int dataDimFrom;
    private int dataDimTo;
    private long samplesCount;
    private int universeSize;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    dataDimFrom = conf.getInt("dataDimFrom", 0);
    dataDimTo = conf.getInt("dataDimTo", 0);
    samplesCount = conf.getLong("samplesCount", 0);
    universeSize = dataDimTo - dataDimFrom + 1;
}

@Override
public void map(
        LongWritable key,
        DoubleArrayWritable array,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DoubleWritable[] outArray = new DoubleWritable[universeSize*2];
    for (int c = 0; c < universeSize; c++) {
        outArray[c] = new DoubleWritable(
                         array.get(c+dataDimFrom).get() / samplesCount);
    }
    for (int c = universeSize; c < universeSize*2; c++) {
        double val = array.get(c-universeSize+dataDimFrom).get();
        outArray[c] = new DoubleWritable((val*val) / samplesCount);
    }
    context.write(new IntWritable(1), new DoubleArrayWritable(outArray));
}

}
```

Combiner:

```java
public class CalculateMeanAndSTDEVCombiner extends
       Reducer <IntWritable,
                DoubleArrayWritable,
                IntWritable,
                DoubleArrayWritable> {

   private int dataDimFrom;
   private int dataDimTo;
   private int universeSize;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    dataDimFrom = conf.getInt("dataDimFrom", 0);
    dataDimTo = conf.getInt("dataDimTo", 0);
    universeSize = dataDimTo - dataDimFrom + 1;
}

@Override
public void reduce(
        IntWritable column,
        Iterable<DoubleArrayWritable> partialSums,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DoubleWritable[] outArray = new DoubleWritable[universeSize*2];
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for (DoubleArrayWritable partialSum : partialSums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < universeSize*2; i++) {
            if (!isFirst) {
                outArray[i].set(outArray[i].get()
                                  + partialSum.get(i).get());
            } else {
                outArray[i]
                    = new DoubleWritable(partialSum.get(i).get());
            }
        }
        isFirst = false;
    }
    context.write(column, new DoubleArrayWritable(outArray));
}

}
```

Reducer:

```java
public class CalculateMeanAndSTDEVReducer extends
       Reducer <IntWritable,
                DoubleArrayWritable,
                IntWritable,
                DoubleArrayWritable> {

   private int dataDimFrom;
   private int dataDimTo;
   private int universeSize;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    dataDimFrom = conf.getInt("dataDimFrom", 0);
    dataDimTo = conf.getInt("dataDimTo", 0);
    universeSize = dataDimTo - dataDimFrom + 1;
}

@Override
public void reduce(
        IntWritable column,
        Iterable<DoubleArrayWritable> partialSums,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    DoubleWritable[] outArray = new DoubleWritable[universeSize*2];
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for (DoubleArrayWritable partialSum : partialSums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < universeSize; i++) {
            if (!isFirst) {
                outArray[i].set(outArray[i].get() + partialSum.get(i).get());
            } else {
                outArray[i] = new DoubleWritable(partialSum.get(i).get());
            }
        }
        isFirst = false;
    }
    for (int i = universeSize; i < universeSize * 2; i++) {
        double mean = outArray[i-universeSize].get();
        outArray[i].set(Math.sqrt(outArray[i].get() - mean*mean));
    }
    context.write(column, new DoubleArrayWritable(outArray));
}

}
```

Where DoubleArrayWritable is simple class which extends ArrayWritable:

```java
public class DoubleArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {

public DoubleArrayWritable() {
    super(DoubleWritable.class);
}

public DoubleArrayWritable(DoubleWritable[] values) {
    super(DoubleWritable.class, values);
}

public DoubleWritable get(int idx) {
    return (DoubleWritable) get()[idx];
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this ´context.write(new IntWritable(1), new DoubleArrayWritable(outArray));´ in your mapper? So your column is always 1?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I see here two solutions:

**1) Mapper procudes pairs:** {1, {partMean1, partMean2, ... partMeanK, partSumSquare1, partSumSquare2, ... partSumSquareK}} (which I described here)

**2) Mapper produces pairs:** {1, {partMean1, partSumSquare1}}, {2, {partMean2, partSumSquare2}}, ... {K, {partMeanK, partSumSquareK}}

_where K - count of variables (columns) in data._

**I tested both, but I haven't got good speedup in the results.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked question about another job in the same environment with the same problem. David Gruzman guessed that problem in the difference job start-time (local, cluster). He suggested optimal size of data to see good speedup (5 GB) in this environment. I tried and it's true.

[Why job with mappers only is so slow in real cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120311/why-job-with-mappers-only-is-so-slow-in-real-cluster)