# Why job with mappers only is so slow in real cluster?

Tags: hadoop

I have a job with mapper PrepareData only which needed for converting text data to *SequencialFile* with *VLongWritable* as a **key** and *DoubleArrayWritable* as a **value**.

When I run it over 455000x90 (~384 Mb) data with lines, for example:

> 13.124,123.12,12.12,... 1.12
>
> 23.12,1.5,12.6,... 6.123
>
> ...

in **local** mode it's takes on average:

1. 51 seconds on Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 5600+, 2.79Ггц;
2. 54 seconds on Athlon 64 Processor 3700+, 1Ггц;

=> 52-53 seconds on average.

but when I run it in real cluster with this 2 machines (Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 5600+, 3700+)  it's takes 81 seconds in best case.

Job executed with 4 mapper (block size ~96 mb) and 2 reducers.

Cluster powered by **Hadoop 0.21.0**, configured for jvm reuse.

**Mapper**:

```java
public class PrepareDataMapper
       extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, VLongWritable, DoubleArrayWritable> {

private int size;

// hint
private DoubleWritable[] doubleArray;
private DoubleArrayWritable mapperOutArray = new DoubleArrayWritable();
private VLongWritable mapOutKey = new VLongWritable();

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    size = conf.getInt("dataDimSize", 0);
    doubleArray = new DoubleWritable[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        doubleArray[i] = new DoubleWritable();
    }
}

@Override
public void map(
        LongWritable key,
        Text row,
        Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] fields = row.toString().split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        doubleArray[i].set(Double.valueOf(fields[i]));
    }
    mapperOutArray.set(doubleArray);
    mapOutKey.set(key.get());
    context.write(mapOutKey, mapperOutArray);
}   
}
```

**DoubleArrayWritable**:

```java
public class DoubleArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {

public DoubleArrayWritable() {
    super(DoubleWritable.class);
}

public DoubleArrayWritable(DoubleWritable[] values) {
    super(DoubleWritable.class, values);
}

public void set(DoubleWritable[] values) {
    super.set(values);
}

public DoubleWritable get(int idx) {
    return (DoubleWritable) get()[idx];
}

public double[] getVector(int from, int to) {
    int sz = to - from + 1;
    double[] vector = new double[sz];
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        vector[i-from] = get(i).get();
    }
    return vector;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can guess that the different is in the job srart-up time. For the local mode it is a few seconds, while for the cluster it is usually dozens of seconds.  
To verify this assumption you can put more data and verify that cluster performance became better then single node. 
Additional possible cause - you might have not enough mappers to fully utilize your hardware. I would suggest trying number of mappers x2 of number of cores you have.

Comment: Cluster configured to utilize only 1 processor on each node. It's needed for benchmarking algorithm with this job as a part.
I trying more data (1 Gb) but nothing good.
How much data I need have to see speedup on Hadoop ?

Comment: Lets try to calculate how much data will diminish job start delay. You process on standalone mode about 8 mb/sec. I would assume that 5 minutes processing will make job startup delay to be less then 15%. So we need 8x60*5*2 MBs of data. We need about 5 GB of data to have 2 computers fully loaded for 5 minutes.

Comment: Anlther point I can consider is differnace in the HDFS performance in standalon and cluster.

Comment: you was right. I tried this job on ~4 GB of data and got 1.5 speedup.